Counting local representations for $\mathrm{GL}_2$
$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}$Some context.
In number theory, it is natural to study distribution questions for the family of elliptic curves over $\mathbb{Q}$ (or any fixed number field for that matter). Any elliptic curve $E_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ has a unique Weierstrass model $y^2=x^3+Ax+B$, where $(A,B)$ is a pair of integers such that for all primes $p$, either $p^4\nmid A$ and $p^6\nmid B$. The height of $E$ is then defined to be maximum of $|A|^3$ and $|B|^2$. The height function satisfies the Northcott property, i.e., the set of isomorphism classes of elliptic curves $E_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ with height $\leq X$ is finite. Moreover, as a function of $X$, it is asymptotic to $\frac{4}{\zeta(10)} X^{\frac{5}{6}}$. The rank distribution conjecture predicts that half of these elliptic curves have rank $0$ and the other half have rank $1$ (as $X\rightarrow \infty$). A density zero set is expected to have rank $\geq 2$. On the other hand, it is natural to also study density questions for elliptic curves with prescribed local conditions. For instance, the proportion of elliptic curves $E_{/\mathbb{Q}}$ that are semistable is somewhat close to $1/\zeta(2)$.
Automorphic forms.
It is natural to study similar distribution questions for modular forms on a given group with prescribed weight. Here, the level of the modular form in question goes to infinity (as opposed to the "height"). These distribution results have been proven via dimension formulas. The question has also been generalized to the context of automorphic forms, cf. for instance, https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07567
Local representations.
This naturally motivates a similar question for irreducible local representations of a fixed group. For simplicity, consider the group $\GL_2(F)$, where $F$ is a fixed local field and consider the set $\text{Irr}(\GL_2(F))$ of all irreducible smooth admissible representations of $\GL_2(F)$ taking values in $\mathbb{C}$. These come in two families, the principal series and the supercuspidals. The principal series are easy to parametrize, the supercuspidals are parametrized by fundamental strata. Is there are good notion of a height function on $\text{Irr}(\GL_2(F))$ that satisfies the Northcott property? Given a representation $\pi$ of $\GL_2(F)$, since $\pi$ is smooth, the restriction of $\pi$ to $\GL_2(O_F)$ factors through a finite index subgroup $K$. Let $K$ be the largest such subgroup and set $\operatorname{ht}(\pi)$ to denote the index $[\GL_2(O_F):K]$. The problem with this definition is that the subset of $\text{Irr}(\GL_2(F))$ with height $<X$ is infinite. This is easy to see for principal series since the characters that are induced from the diagonal are free to take any values on the uniformizer of $O_F$. What would be an appropriate way to rectify this? Perhaps one can consider the subset of $\operatorname{Irr}(\GL_2(F))$ where the values of these uniformizers are prescribed. The same issue comes up when analyzing supercuspidals, but here it seems to be more subtle. Nonetheless, the parametrization is quite explicit.
Questions. Is there a good way to define a counting problem for local representations? What is the significance of "prescribing" the values of the uniformizers on the diagonal, or resort to any other modification of the problem? Maybe one has to further prescribe the $L$-factor?
Some musings. Fix a prime $p$. As we vary over all local representations in the family of modular forms of fixed weight (ordered by level), it is natural to study how the associated local representation varies in $\operatorname{Irr}(\GL_2(F))$. Perhaps there is a natural measure on $\operatorname{Irr}(\GL_2(F))$ which describes this distribution as the bound on the level approaches $\infty$. This is similar to the case of elliptic curves, where there is a natural measure on local models for Weierstrass equations.

The paper 'Counting the discrete series for GL(n)' by Bushnell and Henniart is related to the part about counting local representations. Of course it only addresses discrete series... (Here is a link to the paper: https://academic.oup.com/blms/article-abstract/39/1/133/280568)

Yes, you can count automorphic forms with given local representations.  If you want to count discrete series, you can just fix the $\pi_p$.  For principal series, you can fix a parameter in a small interval.  Let me focus on the case of ramified local representations, which sounds to me like what you are interested in.
The asymptotic count is determined by the Plancherel measure.  For instance, see:
Hilbert modular forms with prescribed ramification, Jared Weinstein
and
Automorphic Plancherel Density Theorem, Sug Woo Shin
The former only counts up to inertia type, which does not pin down the representation--you also need a local sign, but the signs should be equidistributed.
For holomorphic modular forms, you can also do exact counts with dimension formulas.  I worked out the relevant dimension formulas here (where you don't get supercuspidals):
Refined dimensions of cusp forms, and equidistribution and bias of signs
and some supercuspidal cases are done here:
Counting locally supercuspidal newforms, Andrew Knightly
At some point in the near future, I hope to be able to tell you more general exact counts.

This answer is very helpful and certainly answer part of my question. My question has more to do with how one can make sense of counting local representations themselves and how one can parametrize them in the supercuspidal case especially. In these papers it seems that the local representation is a fixed one.  I will take a closer look at the references.

... For instance, as one varies over all automorphic forms, what is the probability that the associated representation at a fixed prime is discrete series (or supercuspidal). Also can one make sense of the question, given a prime p, are there more supercuspidal local representations than discrete series (or vice versa).

what is the probability that the associated representation at a fixed prime is discrete series - It's essentially the probability that the prime divides the level (the only thing to do is subtract off ramified principal series when $p^2 \mid N$ for PGL(2)), so about $1/p$.

I think the thesis of M. Palm should be mentioned in this context. It us available on arxiv: https://arxiv.org/abs/1212.4282

@Kimball For $GL_2 $, as opposed to the $PGL_2$ case you discuss, it matters a lot whether one fixes the central character. If the central character is trivial or at least unramified at $p$ then the probability is close to $1/p$, as you say. For $GL_2$ with arbitrary central character most modular forms of level $p$ will be ramified principal series and the discrete series proportion will be about $3/ (2p^2)$, with $1/p^2$ coming from Steinberg and $1/(2p^2)$ depth zero supercuspidals.

@AnweshRay I am not sure what you mean by "in these paperes it seems that the local representation is a fixed one". The line "Around the same time, Sauvageot ([Sau97]) obtained a similar result in the representation-theoretic setting, which says roughly that if G is an anisotropic group over Q (equivalently if the quotient G(Q)\G(A) is compact) then the p-components of automorphic representations are equidistributed with respect to the Plancherel measure as the level gets deeper and deeper" in the second paper is exactly the sort of thing that is needed to make sense of these questions:

In other words it states that the probability of the associated representation lying in a "reasonable" subset (certainly including the discrete series) is equal to the Plancherel measure of that subset divided by the Plancherel measure of the total space.
